# Window Functions between current row and previous row with specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I want to be able to sum the values in a certain column between the current row the latest previous row with a certain value in another column.

In this example I want to sum the Val Column between the current row and the latest row with a RecType of 2 partitioned by ID ordered by RowNum.

```
DECLARE @ExampleTable TABLE
(
    Id INT,
    RowNum INT,
    RecType INT,
    Val INT
)


INSERT INTO @ExampleTable
    (Id, RowNum, RecType, Val)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1, 1),
    (1, 2, 2, 2),
    (1, 3, 1, 4),
    (1, 4, 1, 8),
    (1, 5, 1, 16),
    (1, 6, 2, 32),
    (1, 7, 1, 64),

    (2, 1, 2, 1),
    (2, 2, 2, 2),
    (2, 3, 1, 4),
    (2, 4, 1, 8),
    (2, 5, 1, 16),
    (2, 6, 1, 32),
    (2, 7, 2, 64)
```

I'm hoping for Results like:

```
DECLARE @Results TABLE
(
    Id  INT,
    RowNum INT,
    SumSinceLast2 INT
)


INSERT INTO @Results
    (Id, RowNum, SumSinceLast2)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 0),
    (1, 2, 0),
    (1, 3, 6), -- 4 + 2
    (1, 4, 14), -- 4 + 2 + 8
    (1, 5, 30), -- 16 + 8 + 4 + 2
    (1, 6, 62), -- 32 + 16 + 8 + 4 + 2
    (1, 7, 96), -- 64 + 32
    (2, 1, 0),
    (2, 2, 3), -- 2 + 1
    (2, 3, 6), -- 4 + 2
    (2, 4, 14), -- 8 + 4 + 2
    (2, 5, 30), -- 16 + 8 + 4 + 2
    (2, 6, 62), -- 32 + 16 + 8 + 4 + 2
    (2, 7, 126) -- 64 + 32 + 16 + 8 + 4 + 2
```

Is this something that I should be able to easily do in SQL Server 2017? I was hoping window functions would be of use here.

Comment: I find the logic a bit confusing.  The rows with value of "2" are summed up to the previous 2?

Comment: @GordonLinoff It's more of a running total between the current row and the previous row with a value of 2 in RecType, if that helps.

Comment: `val`=32 is summed  up twice, in two groups of `RowNum`s of `id` 1. Is it correct?

Comment: @Serg Correct - because i want to sum the current row with all previous rows up to and including the previous row with a rec type of 2. So row num 6 includes it because that window is between row num 2 and row num 6. Row num 7 includes it because that window should be between  row num 6 and row num 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't return exactly what you want, but the results seem more sensible.  Each "2" starts a new group.  The values are then cumulatively summed within the group:

```
select e.*,
        (case when grp_2 = 0
              then 0
              else sum(val) over (partition by id, grp_2 order by rownum)
         end) as result
 from (select e.*,
              sum(case when RecType = 2 then 1 else 0 end) over
                  (partition by id
                   order by rownum
                  ) as grp_2
       from @ExampleTable e
      ) e
 order by id, rownum;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0036c24f251f1aa4d08f6812459ac7d0) is a db<>fiddle.

The results can be tweaked (it makes for a much messier query) to "fix" the values for the "2" the way you have them.  However, this version makes more sense to me, because "2" are not counted in two separate groups.

Here is a tweaked version that double counts the "2"s:

```
 select e.*,
        (case when grp_2 = 0 or grp_2 = 1 and RecType = 2
              then 0
              when RecType <> 2
              then sum(val) over (partition by id, grp_2 order by rownum)
              else sum(val) over (partition by id, grp_2_desc) + lag(val) over (partition by id, Rectype order by rownum)
         end) as result
 from (select e.*,
              sum(case when RecType = 2 then 1 else 0 end) over
                  (partition by id
                   order by rownum
                  ) as grp_2,
              sum(case when RecType = 2 then 1 else 0 end) over
                  (partition by id
                   order by rownum desc
                  ) as grp_2_desc
       from @ExampleTable e
      ) e
 order by id, rownum;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know there is a solution already but since I wrote the code, I am going to post it here anyway.

```
--Sum the range
select 
    et.Id
    ,a.CurrentRow
    ,sum(CASE WHEN ClosestMinRow = CurrentRow THEN 0 ELSE et.Val end) --When there is no previous 2 then set them to 0
from 
    @ExampleTable et
join 
(
    --Create begin and end range
    select 
        et.Id
        ,et.RowNum CurrentRow
        ,ISNULL(FloorRange.RowNum,et.RowNum) ClosestMinRow
    from 
        @ExampleTable ET
    OUTER Apply (
        -- Get the RecType = 2 in order to create a range
        select 
            MAX(RowNum) RowNum
        from 
            @ExampleTable et2
        WHERE 
            RecType = 2
            AND et2.RowNum < ET.RowNum
            AND et2.Id = et.Id
    ) FloorRange
) a
    ON et.Id = a.Id
    and et.RowNum between a.ClosestMinRow and CurrentRow
GROUP BY 
    et.Id
    ,a.CurrentRow
order by 
    et.Id
    ,a.CurrentRow
```